# Python: How to make a string to a list using a substring?

Tags: python

For example I have a string like this...

```
StringA = "a city a street a room a bed"
```

I want to cut this string using a substring `"a "` and make a `list` from it. So the result looks like...

```
ListA = ["city ", "street " ,"room " ,"bed"]
```

It would be OK if there are some empty spaces left. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Note, all given answers will not work if you have a string containing a word ending in `a`, like `a cola`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should also work:

```
ListA = StringA.split("a ")[1:]
```

The [1:] after the split statement has been added because the part before the first 'a' (which is '')  will be treated as the first element of ListA and you don't want that.

Your output will look exactly like the one you desire:

```
ListA = ['city ', 'street ', 'room ', 'bed']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`:

```
list_a = string_a.split('a ')
```

Comment: Fails if `StringA = "a cola a street a room a bed"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line:

```
filter(len, "a city a street a room a bed".split("a "))
```

Comment: `filter()` will return `filter` object.

Comment: It returns a list

Comment: Alright, i'm sorry, for python 2 [yes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), for python 3 [no](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Answer (score 0):

This will make list from string:

```
re.split(r'\s*\ba\b\s*', a)
```

Output should be something like this:

```
['', 'city', 'cola', 'room', 'bed']
```

So, to remove empty strings from list You can use:

```
[item for item in re.split(r'\s*\ba\b\s*', a) if item]
```

Which will produce:

```
['city', 'cola', 'room', 'bed']
```